# Recolor Cmidrule to the same color as hrule

Tags: latex

I am trying to create a table with a midrule (cmidrule to skip the first column) however this cmidrule takes on a different color than hrule. And I cannot change the color of cmidrule using packages like the way one could recolor midrule.

```
\begin{tabular}{lcccc}
   \hline 
         & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Value-Weighted} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Equal-Weighted}\\
  \cmidrule{2-5}
 & Equity Premium & Information Ratio & Equity Premium & Information Ratio \\ 
  \hline
\end{tabular}
```

I would like to have the table with lines in equal color (note that I do use hrule everywhere in my document so preferably to the color of hrule)

Comment: Can you please make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not mix `\hline` and rule commands. If you use a coherent styling of your table, there is no problem.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs,colortbl}

\begin{document}
\arrayrulecolor{red}
\begin{tabular}{lcccc}
  % \hline 
  \toprule
  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Value-Weighted} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Equal-Weighted}\\
  \cmidrule{2-5}
 & Equity Premium & Information Ratio & Equity Premium & Information Ratio \\ 
  \bottomrule
  %\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT**:
It is very strange to see `\hrule` used in an automatically generated table. But, to solve your problem, it depends on the situation.

1/ your `\hrule` are colored and you want the same color in your other table rules.

In that case look at the generated code. There should be something like

```
\color{blue}\hrule width 1cm
```

or

```
\color{\mycolor}\hrule width 1cm
```

Pick up whatever color is used by the \hrule and issue at the start of your document

```
\arrayrulecolor{\mycolor} % or whatever is used by the \hrule
```

And all the rules in your table should have a similar color.

2/ Your \hrule are black and you want to color them.

*Please don't.*

\hrule is a very low level TeX command, and there is no way to configure its color simply. More, its syntax is complex. You can have

```
\hrule                 % draw a thin line that is \textwidth wide
```

or

```
\hrule height 2p width 3cm depth 0.5ex % specify parameters of the rule
```

or more or less anything in-between.

The basic method that can be used to redefine \hrule would be

```
\let\mybasehrule=\hrule              % save definition of \hrule
\def\hrule{\color{blue}\mybasehrule} % and redefine it
```

But you should **immediately** after the `\hrule` issue a `\color{black}` to switch back to the initial color, otherwise, anything you generate will be blue. It the `\hrule` is **always** followed by a macro in your table, you can redefine this macro in a similar way and hope that there will be no exception with a `\hrule` followed by another command. If you cannot identify such a macro, you are trapped.

And you **must** turn back to the initial definition of `\hrule` after your table. `\hrule` is a very basic TeX macro used directly or indirectly by virtually any package that you use and you do not want to have `\hrule`  redefined and turning randomly all your text to blue.

In my opinion, it would probably be simpler to rewrite the driver to generate sane tabular code than to redefine `\hrule` to generate colored rules in tables...

Comment: Is there also a possibility of solving this with hrules instead of other rules? Xtable in R exports every table with hrule and I have over 50 tables the format of the tables also get very bold using top and bottomrules.

Comment: This is weird. They should use standard table commands instead of \hrule... What you can do is to set the same color for hrule and booktabs rules with \arrayrulecolor.

Comment: @bart I did some edit in my answer to explain how to deal with \hrule.